# Why second run of a function in for loop returns an empty string?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to parse text to extract only the lists of usernames in between the semicolons. Below are the logs and code.

Relevant Server Side Code:

```
    function getChats(position,row){
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pIC6Lyx4Q0ZjEA5GURZ3gA5qLmUJ0_7yGPJQmr6-GnQ");
        var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
        var row3 = Number(row);
        var row2 = parseInt(row3);
        var row = String(row2);
        var range = ('S' + row);
        var value = subsheet.getRange(range).getValue();
        Logger.log(value + ", " + row);
        Logger.log(position + ", " + (position - 1));
        var pos1 = value.indexOf(";",position - 1);
        var pos2 = value.indexOf(";",position);
        var content = value.slice(pos1 + 1,pos2);
        Logger.log(pos1 + " " + pos2 + " " + content);
        return content;
    }
```

Relevant Client Side Code:

```
function repeater(openChats){
        alert("Open Chats: " + openChats);
        for (i = 1; i <= Number(openChats); i++){
            alert("Repetition: " + i);

            google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(displayChatOptions)
              .getChats(i*2,sessionStorage.getItem('row'));

            //API call above is supposed to run for ever for-loop iteration.

        }
        if (Number(openChats) >= 10){
            var link = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            link.id = "newChatOption";
            link.innerHTML = "Chat Limit Reached";
            link.onclick = "alert('There is currently a limit of 10 chats per Echo Account due to how we handle you data. Updates in the future will enable unlimited chats per Echo Account.')";
            link.className = 'button';
            document.getElementById("sidenav").appendChild(link);
        }
        else{
            var link = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            link.id = "newChatOption";
            link.innerHTML = "Create New Chat";
            link.onclick = 'newChat()';
            link.className = 'button';
            document.getElementById("sidenav").appendChild(link);
            document.getElementById("sidenav").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        }
        chats = openChats;
  }
```

Logs:
[image: Logs]

For some reason, when the function is called from the client-side for the second time, it returns blank text instead of the second set of names. How can I fix this? The first time I call the function from the for-loop on the client-side, it returns what I want and works correctly. However, the second time I run the function, it returns `""` (empty string).

Comment: where is `displayChatOptions`? provide [mcve]

Comment: Please specify which variable `returns blank text instead of the second set of names`. How is `repeater` being called? Be aware that you have several simultaneous calls because of the `for` loop.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - why you put "limit reached" alert in a button that user has to click which pops up an `alert()`, blocking the UI? +In additoon to Alan's answer, you can introduce [caching](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service) to server-side calls (or at least move `openById()` to a getter with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Btw, what happens when a curious user changes `sessionStorage` - your `getChats` func will try to get the row user set instead.

Comment: displayChatOptions work properly which is why I didn't think I needed to include it in my client-side code. I just realized that users can edit sessionStorage. I am currently developing a script that runs in the background that makes sure that the username, password, and row are valid. If not it logs the user out and clears the sessions storage. This way if a user edits the session storage they will have to have the other users password to access their account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from documentation:

> The google.script.run API allows 10 concurrent calls to server
>   functions.

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions)

You have a `google.script.run` call in a `for` loop.  Subsequent `google.script.run` calls in the `for` loop don't wait until the previous call is complete before making another call to the server.  That results in multiple concurrent calls to the same server function.

What is happening, is that your client side code is running faster than the Google Apps Script server code is running, so before the server function `getChats` has completed, it's being called again.  And when that happens, the previous values in the variables get overwritten.

The server function `getChats(position,row)` isn't running separate, individual instances of the function.  Before the first run instance is complete, the function is being called again.  You're trying to run multiple instances of the same function concurrently.

As indicated by the documentation quote, there can only be 10 concurrent calls to the server at a time.  If you were calling 10 different function names, then that would be different.  All 10 functions with different names would run independently. But, creating lots of identical functions with different names isn't a good solution.

You could use LockService.

Quote from documentation:

> Prevents concurrent access to sections of code. This can be useful
>   when you have multiple users or processes modifying a shared resource
>   and want to prevent collisions.

But depending upon how many times `google.script.run` is called, and how long the code runs, you could run into hitting quota limits.  There are short term and long term limits.  Even if the code is under the long term limit, you could easily hit short term limits because of calling `SpreadsheetApp.openById` multiple times in rapid succession.

So, what should you do?
You could pass all the data to the server function at once, instead of once on every loop.

```
var arrayToSendToServer = [];

for (i = 1; i <= Number(openChats); i++){
    console.log("Repetition: " + i);
    arrayToSendToServer.push(sessionStorage.getItem('row'));
}

google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(displayChatOptions)
  .getChats(arrayToSendToServer);
```

Then get the spreadsheet only once, and loop through the array, compiling data to send back.  Then send the compiled data back.

This is just an example.  I'm sure that it has errors in it.  It's just for giving you an idea of what to do.

```
function getChats(arrayOfData){
  var content,pos1,pos2,range,value;

  var dataToSendBack = [];

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ABC_123");
    var subsheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");

    L = arrayOfData.length;

    for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
      range = ('S' + i.toString());
      value = subsheet.getRange(range).getValue();

      Logger.log(value + ", " + row);
      Logger.log(position + ", " + (position - 1));

      pos1 = value.indexOf(";",position - 1);
      pos2 = value.indexOf(";",position);
      content = value.slice(pos1 + 1,pos2);

      Logger.log(pos1 + " " + pos2 + " " + content);

      dataToSendBack.push(content);
  }

  return dataToSendBack;
}
```